# Performing actions with "tab" key

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox1(writable), textbox2(writable), and textbox3(Read-only, "greyed-out"). The user will input an integer value on texbox1 and textbox2 and when the user hits the "tab" key on the keyboard I want the value from the division of textbox1 and textbox2 to appear automatically in textbox3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, and your question has nothing to do with the Visual Studio IDE. I've removed the tags and edited your title accordingly; your question is simply about vb.net.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET or Windows desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code on the KeyDown event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab then

'whatever you want to do here

end if

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) EventHandler that will expose the Keycode that you need use to check for the <kbd>Tab</kbd>  in its [`PreviewKeyDownEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I am also verifying that you actually have integers in TextBox1 and TextBox2 by using the [`Integer.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Private Sub TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown, TextBox2.PreviewKeyDown
    Dim value1, value2 As Integer
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, value1) And Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, value2) Then
            TextBox3.Text = CStr(value1 / value2)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```